# Express - net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Tags: jquery, express

Using Express, I make a simple a POST request using JQuery. Randomly, it comes back with an error saying

`net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH`

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

In the Express file, I was accidentally calling `next()` after calling `res.json()`. You should not call `next()` after sending a response.